# C program that connects to index.php on xampp server

Tags: c, sockets, winsock2, socketserver, winsockets

I am looking to setup a C client that can communicate with an index.php file running on a local XAMPP server.

All the tutorials online are based on creating a C client and connecting to a C server. But how would I connect a C client to a PHP file on an xampp server?

Would I need to open sockets on both the C client and also the index.php file using sockets in PHP? Or can I just open a socket in the C program and point it to say localhost/index.php?

The C client will listen for HTTP messages from the server where the index.php will be hosted. The index.php file will contain a html form where I can enter a sentence and the C program will then print that sentence into the computers terminal.

Would it be possible to connect the C program to the server. Then use the exec() command in the index.php form as a POST request and send this to the C program through a socket?

Any help or known articles would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Connect what and how exactly? What does your PHP server do and what does it communicate to the C client? If you indeed want to use sockets, then just open sockets - the client shouldn't care what language the server is written in (and vice versa)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. At the moment i am looking to create a basic c client which will listen for messages from the php file, I would like to be able to enter a sentence into a html form for example and it will print the results in the terminal of the PC running the C client. I am fine with the PHP. Just not sure where to start with the C programming.

Comment: Don't comment your question but do **edit your question** to improve it. It is still unclear, and need improvements (e.g. explain what you want in terms of HTTP requests, and what your C client should do). Give more context & motivations.

Comment: Do you have access to the PHP source code? Could you improve it? Consider designing some  [web service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) independently of the emitted HTML code and of HTML forms in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you actually want to achieve, i.e. what you mean by 'connect' a c program to an `index.php` ?

The first thing you should realize is that what we are talking about here are two processes: (a) the c program and (b) whatever interpreter that executes the PHP script (Probably a web server).

You want to exchange data between two processes, thus we talk about **Interprocess Communication**.

In the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) you see a table listing several means:

- Files: Your PHP script could write to a file, the c program read from it (or, under Unix, Pipes would be even better suited)
- Sockets: Just as you mentioned already, one of the programs could establish a connection via sockets and exchange their data over this connection.
- other means (have a look at the table)

Since your PHP script is probably run within a web server, the socket solution would be promising:
The web server already listens for incoming connections, and provides a decent protocol to exchange data: **HTTP** .

I will not repeat the answer by Basile , but just give an example for how to exchange some data between the c program and the PHP script with a web server using CGI:

The web server provides a URL, that will invoke the PHP script, like `http://test.me/test.php` .

Now, the procedure would be:

1. The C program establishes a TCP connection to socket test.me:80
2. The c program sends over a **HTTP GET** request by transmitting text in the form of

   `GET /test.php?a=31&b=19 http/1.1`
3. The server will invoke the index.php, providing it with the key value pairs a=31, b=19
4. The script will do stuff, and print something to stdout like:

   `abc`

(This is not a valid HTTP response, but its sufficient to scetch the procedure in general)

5. The web server will send back the output of the php script `abc` over the connection to the c program.

As you see, in this example, you transferred

1. a=31, b=19 from the c program to the web server/index.php
2. `abc` from the web server/index.php to the c program

In general, the best solution depends on what you want to accomplish. I assume your example is just an example, and you could solve it the way I drafted above. However,  if you really just wanted to have something printed to your console, just have your index.php write it to a file/pipe and the c program read the file...

This way or the other, I feel there is much for you to explore ...

Furthermore, I want to clarify one last thing:
I used 'c program' for the sake of simplicity, but i need not be a c program, but your problem referrs to an arbitrary process, it could also be a python script run by the python interpreter or ...

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't communicate with a PHP file, but with some Web server running that PHP program (such as Apache, part of [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP)) for some HTTP requests. Spend several hours or days reading about [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) (you need to understand it in some details and be aware of HTTP [requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_message), responses, [headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields), [cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie), etc...). **Reason in terms of the HTTP protocol** (what kind of HTTP requests should your C application make?). Look with your browser into the HTTP requests sent by it.

Then, what you want to use is some HTTP client library in C, like [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

(Be also aware that HTTP server libraries exist in C, e.g. [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/); you probably don't need that here)

Perhaps [websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) could be useful to you, but probably not.

> The C client will listen for HTTP messages

If the C program is *listening* (with [Berkeley sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets), using some [listen(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html) or the equivalent on your system) it is not a client but a server. If it is a client it will *emit* HTTP *requests*  -using [connect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) & [send(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html)- (and process the corresponding HTTP *responses*), and you'll better use a library (like `libcurl`) for that (because in the details HTTP is quite complex), that will handle low level details like `connect` , `send`, [recv(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) etc... and the buffering at your place.

> The index.php file will contain a html form

That usually means some [`POST` request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)). Details depend upon the [`<form` HTML element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_(HTML)).